# cannot make android project with latest gradle version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

I am using `intellij idea` 2017.03 and I am using it for android developments. Currently when I create project it takes `gradle` version as 2.2.3. but current version is 4. So I am trying to make my project `gradle` version to latest one.
I tried to update it via `build.gradle` file, but it didn't work. I know that new android studio update will fix this, but in there release notes they have mentioned that Android studio built on `intellij idea` 2017.03. so how can I make it works?

Answer (score 0):

This is the line you have, right:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

Gradle `classpath` versions are different from the actual Gradle versions for some reason.

Change the version there to `3.1.4`, and make sure you have the following line in `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Comment: yes. i tried it too. but then i got following error.`This Gradle plugin requires a newer IDE able to request IDE model level 3. For Android Studio this means version 3.0+`

Comment: You should really be using Android Studio for Android development. That, or update to IntelliJ 2018.